# How do I make CREATE DATABASE command re-runnable in SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'd like to create a script that simply drops and creates a database over and over in PostgreSQL.
For a table this is not problem with the following:

> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test CASCADE;
>
> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test (   Sample varchar );

The above code works, no problem.
However, when I try to do the same for a database, ie:

> DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS sample;
>
> CREATE DATABASE sample;

I get the following error:
ERROR:  DROP DATABASE cannot run inside a transaction block
SQL state: 25001

Any idea how I can get the database to be created and dropped repetitively without doing it manually?

Comment: Disable the transaction demarcation in your tool? What tool are you using to run SQL statements?

Comment: I'm running PostgreSQL. Should've mentioned that in original post

Comment: How would I disable the transaction demarcation?

Comment: PostgreSQL is the database engine running as a server. The problem is not there, but resides in the client application you are using to send SQL statements to the engine: maybe you are using Toad, SQuirrel SQL Client, or other to connect to PostgreSQL. For some reason your app/tool has "transaction demarcation" activated, maybe by default. Search for an "autocommit" option (or similar) and activate it.

Comment: Enabled autocommit. Same error. Tried toggling off and back on just to make sure but no change. Any other ideas? Not sure what client application/tool I am using. pgAdmin? I'm very new to the software.

Comment: Is this actually in a script, e.g. a file? Or are you entering each line by hand in a client? Where did you toggle `autocommit`? What is the thing you are entering the commands in, a command line terminal, a browser window, etc?

Comment: Entering in a query tool client by hand. Toggled autocommit in toolbar next to execute button.

Comment: When seemly simple things do not work then perhaps it is time to *Check your basic assumptions*. Check your current database: **select current_database();** You cannot drop the database you are connected to.

Comment: Perfect. Was trying to drop database while connected to it. Thanks @Belayer,